# Riley Riddle #12 - Blessed be this riddle

Tags: riddle

Start with a cartoonish container for dough
End with what makes a bull go
The middle's a unit to sell a thing we don't make
Violet is one of my lakes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I pray this may be

> sacred

Start with a cartoonist container of dough

> sac - in cartoons a thief often runs off with a sac(k) of money (dough), and [sac](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/sac) may mean this loot.

End with what makes a bull go

> Like a red rag to make a bull charge saying.

The middle's a unit to sell a thing we don't make

> acre - a common unit of land area which may be valued.

Violet is one of my lakes

> Violet Lake is on the island of Maui and is important to traditional Hawaiian religion.